# Uploadify check progress

Tags: javascript, uploadify

I need disable submit button while the file is uploading..

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default">Odeslat</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
   'swf' : 'css/uploadify.swf',
   'uploader' : 'uploadify.php?galerie=<?php echo $n; ?>',
   'onUploadProgress' : function(file) {
       $('#submit_button').prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

But this isn't working..

**EDIT**

The correct solution:

```
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({

        'swf': 'css/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php?galerie=<?php echo $n; ?>',
        'onUploadProgress' : function(file) {
            $('#submit_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        'onUploadComplete': function(file) {
            $('#submit_button').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
  });
```

Comment: Are you using jquery ui? If so, it is possible that the button actually is disabled, it just doesn't look like it visually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
   'swf' : 'css/uploadify.swf',
   'uploader' : 'uploadify.php?galerie=<?php echo $n; ?>',
   'onUploadProgress' : function(file) {
       $('#submit_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   },
   'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                   $('#submit_button').removeAttr("disabled")
         }
});
```

Comment: Although `.prop` allows a String for the second parameter, a `Boolean` is preferred. A code sample in the jQuery's documentation describes, [`$( "input" ).prop( "disabled", false );`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/prop2)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks for the tip , did i deserve down vote for this ? lol